# Запрет автозаполнения input html

Tags: html, input, пароль, password

Логинюсь на сайте, сохраняю логин и пароль в браузере, когда спрашивает сохранить или нет. Реализована функция смены пароля, но что бы сменить пароль надо ввести старый пароль в `input type="password"`.

Вот тут возникает загвоздка: по дабл-клику на `input` предлагает сохранённый пароль. Как этого избежать?

Например, ВК даже если ты сохранил пароль в браузере, то в поле ввода старого пароля, при его смене, также по дабл-клику ничего не предлагает.

Короче говоря - как запретить предлагать автозаполнение `input`?

Comment: Разве `input type=password` сохраняет автодополнение? Обескуражен. Может у вас там в слове password опечатка и инпут воспринимается как текст

Comment: Нет, там точно input type=password, ведь текст идёт в маске звёздочек

Comment: Все просто: onfocus="javascript: this.removeAttribute('readonly')" readonly autocomplete="off"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи есть атрибут `autocomplete`.

Для запрета используй:

```
autocomplete="off"
```